# How to use choice in try catch block using apache Camel in a Route with Java DSL

Tags: apache-camel

How to use choice in try catch block using Apache Camel in a Route with Java DSL?

I have a situation in which, I need the following structure:

> route-->from--> doTry-->choice-->when-->simple-->to-->otherwise-->to-->enddoTry-->docatch-->to-->enddocatch-->endroute

As of now I tried below lines:

```
    .doTry()
    .choice()
    .when(header("CamelFileName").contains("xxxxx"))
    .to()
    .otherwise().to("controlbus:route?routeId=XXXX&action=stop")
    .doCatch(java.lang.Exception.class)
    .log("STOPPING ROUTE")
    .to("controlbus:route?routeId=XXXX&action=stop&async=true")
```

But I am getting "**cannot find symbol**" error at `docatch()`

Could you please suggest way to use "choice" in try catch block with Java DSL?

Comment: Please suggest how to end blocks in java DSL
like
endDoTry(),endDoCatch().end()..
Still how many endXXX reserved words are present ,
if possible any example
thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this. This should work

```
.doTry()
    .choice()
      .when(header("CamelFileName").contains("xxxxx"))
        .to()
      .otherwise()
        .to("controlbus:route?routeId=XXXX&action=stop")
.endDoTry()
.doCatch(java.lang.Exception.class)
.log("STOPPING ROUTE")
.to("controlbus:route?routeId=XXXX&action=stop&async=true")
```

Comment: Thanks it worked fine.

I have few more lines after doCatch()
I added endDoCatch but with no luck same error "cannot find symbol"

please suggest where to use "endDoCatch" in below structure

    .doTry()
    .choice()
    .when(header("CamelFileName").contains("xxxxx"))
    .to()
    .otherwise().to("controlbus:route?routeId=XXXX&action=stop")
    .doCatch(java.lang.Exception.class)
    .log("STOPPING ROUTE")
    .to("controlbus:route?routeId=XXXX&action=stop&async=true")
    .endDoCatch().log("try - catch block end").log("")...

Comment: few more lines like what. did u try using just `.end()`. end will end the current bloc, which in your case is catch block

Comment: Thanks @pvpkiran This also worked fine.
My final structure is 
    .doTry()
    .choice()
    .when(header("CamelFileName").contains("xxxxx"))
    .to()
    .otherwise().to("controlbus:route?routeId=XXXX&action=stop")
    .endDoTry()
    .doCatch(java.lang.Exception.class)
    .log("STOPPING ROUTE")
    .to("controlbus:route?routeId=XXXX&action=stop&async=true")
    .end().log()

Comment: interceptFrom("servlet*").when(body().isNull()).to("direct:syntaxError").stop -  i found this in google 
but how the same can also be done in spring xml.
Please let me know the code snippet for above JAVA DSL code
Thanks in advance